# provided invalid Date format error in Vue ApexCharts

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datetime, web, apexcharts

I'm try to draw multiple charts in the Vue page.

This is my chartOptions.

```
this.chartOptions[i] = {
      xaxis: {
        type: "datetime",
        categories: measure_at[i]
      },
      yaxis: {
        labels: {
          minWidth: 10
        }
      },
      zoom: {
        enabled: false
      },
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      },
      stroke: {
        width: [3, 3, 3],
        curve: "straight",
        dashArray: [0, 3, 3]
      },
      markers: {
        size: [6, 0, 0],
        hover: {
          sizeOffset: 10
        }
      },
      grid: {
        borderColor: "#f1f1f1"
      },
      colors: ["#757575", MEASUREMENT_COLORS[1], MEASUREMENT_COLORS[2]],
      tooltip: {
        enabledOnSeries: [0]
      }
    };
```

As you can see, the type of my xaxis is "datetime", and categories code is like this.

```
measure_at[i] = new Date(
        data.records[i].measure_at * 1000
```

When I run my code, the following error occurs and the chart cannot be displayed[image]

And When I log chartOptions[i], it seems to be the correct datetime format

[image]

Comment: Please post text, not images. The date format in the categories array is not supported by ECMA-262, so parsing is implementation dependent. Given the unusual format, it will almost certainly result in an invalid Date.

Comment: But I use date.toLocaleString() to handle my categories. It should be in datetime format?

Comment: There is no expectation that the string created by *toLocaleString* can be parsed by the built–in parser, quite the opposite.

Comment: One other option is to provide timestamps in the xaxis.categories instead of a date strings.